# Why can't k8s find my configmap to mount it as a file?

Tags: kubernetes

I have what I believe to be the simplest of k8s deployments using a configmap value as a file and it refuses to work, instead returning this error message:

```
The Pod "configmap-demo-pod" is invalid: spec.containers[0].volumeMounts[0].name: Not found: "the-thing"
```

This is a watered-down version of what I found [in the documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/) so I am completely at a loss as to what I'm missing.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: demo
data:
  the-thing: |
    hello

---


apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: configmap-demo-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: demo
      image: alpine
      command: ["sleep", "3600"]
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: "/"
        name: the-thing
  volumes:
    - name: config
      configMap:
        name: demo
        items:
        - key: the-thing
          path: "filename"
```

Comment: Your configmap volume is named `config`, not `the-thing`. Separately, it seems highly unlikely you want to mount it on `/`; that will probably result in nothing working.

Comment: Sorry, but could you walk me through that a little more?  If the volume mount doesn't have the name of the config item it's supposed to put in the file, how does it know what to put in there?  If I had a second config item called `the-other-thing` how would I indicated which data goes on which file of they both have `config` in the mount point name?  As for the `/` mount point, that can be anything at this point and I thought leaving it as `/` would reduce complications for the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined a volume like this:

```
  volumes:
    - name: config
      configMap:
        name: demo
        items:
        - key: the-thing
          path: "filename"
```

The volume is named `config`, because you have `name: config`. It refers to a `ConfigMap` named `demo`, and you are (trying to) explicitly include just a single key, named `the-thing`.

When you mount this volume in a container, you refer to it using the name you assigned to the volume, `config`. So:

```
volumeMounts:
  - name: config
    mountPath: /some/path
```

You would never want `mountPath` to be `/` because that would attempt to mount the volume over the contents of the filesystem root, which would result in an unusable container.

---

But let's take a brief step back.

Given a `ConfigMap` with multiple keys, like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: demo
data:
  the-thing: |
    hello
  an-example: |
    this is a test
```

We can expose *all* the keys as files on the filesystem like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  an-example: |
    this is a test
  the-thing: |
    hello
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: demo
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: configmap-demo-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - sleep
    - inf
    image: alpine
    name: demo
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /config
      name: config
  volumes:
  - configMap:
      name: demo
    name: config
```

If we were to deploy those into kubernetes, we would find:

```
$ kubectl exec -it configmap-demo-pod -- sh
/ # ls /config
an-example  the-thing
/ # cat /config/the-thing
hello
/ # cat /config/an-example
this is a test
/ #
```

If we want to expose a subset of the available keys, we can modify the volume definition to specify a list of keys *and paths*, like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: configmap-demo-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: demo
      image: alpine
      command:
        - sleep
        - inf
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: "/config"
        name: config
  volumes:
    - name: config
      configMap:
        name: demo
        items:
          - key: the-thing
            path: another-thing
```

Here, `items` provides a list of the keys we want to expose, along with the corresponding name they will have in the filesystem. In this example, we're exposing the key `the-thing` as a file named `another-thing`. Deploying using this manifest gets us:

```
$ kubectl exec -it configmap-demo-pod -- sh
/ # ls /config
another-thing
/ # cat /config/another-thing
hello
/ #
```

The above two examples expose the `ConfigMap` as a directory, and give you access to either all available keys (the first example) or a subset of the keys (the second example). It's also possible to expose a specific key as a file at an arbitrary location in the filesystem using the `subPath` option on your `volumeMount` configuration, like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: configmap-demo-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: demo
      image: alpine
      command:
        - sleep
        - inf
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: "/etc/the-thing"
        name: config
        subPath: the-thing
  volumes:
    - name: config
      configMap:
        name: demo
```

Deploying that gives us:

```
[lars@madhatter k8s]$ kubectl exec -it configmap-demo-pod -- sh
/ # cat /etc/the-thing
hello
```

Comment: I've converted this answer into a deployable demo that you can find [here](https://github.com/larsks/sf-example-1104641-configmaps).

Comment: This was very thorough and fantastically helpful, thank you!